# NuGet package for .NET System.Drawing.Common 4.5.1 contains incorrect version of assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

I am trying to use `System.Drawing.Common` in project depending on (legacy) .NET Standard 2.0. If I try to target Standard 2.1, I experience compatibility issues with one of my dependencies, [pythonnet](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet), so I need to stick to 2.0 until pythonnet has official support for .NET Standard. Currently, pythonnet can import my assemblies if they target .NET Standard 2.0, but won't for .NET Standard 2.1.

For .NET Standard 2.0 compatibility, the most recent package available is [System.Drawing.Common 4.5.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.5.1). After installing this, my solution builds but at runtime I receive the error

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'System.Drawing is not supported on this platform.'
```

According to [this page](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Drawing.Common/4.5.1), this version of the `System.Drawing.Common` package should be able to target .NET Standard 2.0. I found that the NuGet package contains several `System.Drawing.Common.dll` files for different platforms, but a file version of 4.6.2.

[image: NuGet package containing mismatched version of assembly]

Am I missing something or is this an error in the NuGet package? It seems like this would be the case.

Comment: What runtime is your project targetting?

Comment: @yaakov (correction) .NET Core 2.1

Comment: I changed the target framework to .NET Framework 4.8 as a temporary workaround, and now it is working as expected (this is not a *real* solution but "at least it works on my machine" #WOMM)

Answer (score 1):

The version numbers isn't a problem. There's no requirement or guarantee that any of the Assembly Version, File Version, or Package Version all match.

The PlatformNotSupportedException will be coming from some other problem, though looking through the package I'm not quite sure what. A lot depends on how your project is actually built and run.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had **2 .NET Core App projects** and one was **dependent on the other** *(So that I can execute the app from the other app)*. The thing with .NET Core applications is that they need additional files to work (like
`<assembly name>.deps.json` *(which was the culprit)* and `<assembly name>.runtimeconfig.json`) and for some reason **they don't get copied on build**.

---

Crude solution I did was **adding copy command** to the dependent project's **build events** like this

```
COPY "$(SolutionDir)<dependency project>\$(OutDir)<assembly name>.runtimeconfig.json" "$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\$(OutDir)" /Y
COPY "$(SolutionDir)<dependency project>\$(OutDir)<assembly name>.deps.json" "$(SolutionDir)$(ProjectName)\$(OutDir)" /Y
```

but copying them by hand should also do the trick.